# .NET url encoding ala chrome

Tags: .net, google-chrome, jira, urlencode, jql

Hi guys I'm using jira REST API to get issues using JQL. The problem I have is url encoding in .NET.

I jave an url like so `http://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=status="V řešení"` and when encode it in .NET i get

```
http://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=status%3d%22V+%c5%99e%c5%a1en%c3%ad%22
```

but with URL like that i get Bad Request error from jira

> "errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\u0025' instead.

but when I pass url to google chrome it encodes it as

```
http://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=status%3d"V+řešení"
```

**which works abosultly fine with jira.**

So the question I have is how do I make .NET to encode url same way as google chrome does?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much utilization your library will get, you may not need to encode the entire URL string. Doing *urlString.Replace(" ","+").Replace("=","%3d")* might suffice, so that only the characters that need to be encoded actually are.

Comment: Yes but this way I would have to do a lot of work arround parsing query parameters and then reencoding them my self. I was hoping that there are some standarts with rfc or samething.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are parsing query parameters?  Once the pre-processing is done to build the query string, you should be able to take the fully formed url and apply the 'replace' commands on the whole thing rather than individually on every query key-value pair